# Sending e-mail in large numbers

Tags: smtp, email

I am developing an application that needs to inform users (around 1800) on a regular basis (weekly).

I consider **gmail** but it has a 500 mail in 24 policy, **Google groups** don't have an API,
I contact my **web hosting company**  (bluehost) about the situation, they don't return with an adequate answer (they don't mention the exact number that I can send daily )

Any suggestion would be great...

Thanks

Comment: You aren't informing them that they can `ENL4RGE THE1R P3NI5`, are you?

Comment: are you developing an application to send spam?

Comment: Have you followed up with your hosting provider, asking for clarification?

Comment: I was *soooo* tempted to change the question's title to say "Spamming"

Comment: sounds like a typical newsletter email.  Why would it necessary be spam?

Comment: @Mark Rushakoff: Good point....and if I had responded to all those mine would be about 10m long by now!

Comment: Well, we won't send spam, all 1800 members are registered users to a community and what we are trying to send mails about the meetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web host should allow sending of mass emails, and should have facility to set up reverse DNS etc on your smtp server, since its not uncommon for the web? 
1800 mails is a relatively low in my opinion.

Signing up to a email marketing provider as Shoban mentioned is probably the best option.

Comment: well, as it turns out, 1800 mails is a small number, so with proper opt in/out links, there is no problem. Mailman solves the problem.

by the way, to prove that it is not spam, it is the mailing list of applicants in etohum, which is a YC/Seedcamp counterpart in Turkey.

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Well you dont have much options left

1. Change your hosting provider
2. Use a paid email marketing provider like [graphicmail](http://www.graphicmail.com/site/default.aspx)