# Is there a way to create mass email accounts from your cPanel or using PHP?

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I need to create a big number of emails accounts for my domain to accomplish a task. I was wondering if there is a way of doing this automatically. Maybe through cPanel or PHP.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Does [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579009/sending-e-mail-in-large-numbers) help at all?

Comment: Do you mean create a large number of email **Accounts**

Comment: @Nikolai This question has been closed as off topic. This question is more suitable for ServerFault.com. Could you please post it there. Or maybe the moderators here can migrate it to ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating email accounts without using cPanel directly you can use [cPanel & WHM's API](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/WebHome#cPanel%20%20WHM%27s%20API).

Look at the following forum post, it deals with same thing.

[Create Email Account using API](http://forums.cpanel.net/f42/create-email-account-using-api-121741.html)

Note: the XML-PHP API has moved to GitHub and is available at following link https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php
You can download the 1.0.12 release from https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php/zipball/v1.0.12

In the zip look at `api1_example.php` in Examples directory it is what you want.

*Update*
In short you can do it like this from a PHP script

```
include("../xmlapi.php");

$ip = ip.of.your.server;
$root_pass = 'password_of_your_root_account';

$account = "cpanel_username";

// Email account to create
$email_user = "somerandomuser";
$email_password = "adfm90f1m3f0m0adf";
$email_domain = "somedomain.com";
$email_quota = '10';

// initialize api
$xmlapi = new xmlapi($ip);
$xmlapi->password_auth("root",$root_pass);
$xmlapi->set_output('json');

$xmlapi->set_debug(1);
print $xmlapi->api1_query($account, "Email", "addpop", array($email_user, $email_password, $email_quota, $email_domain) );
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. Will this create something like email1@domain.com, email2@domain.com ?

Comment: @Nikolai This question has been closed as off topic. This question is more suitable for ServerFault.com. Could you please post it there.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Fantastico or Softaculous (or some other script installation wizard) on your cPanel (look for it under Software/Services) then you may be able to install a mailing list application and use that.

Comment: Can you tell me of one mailing list app?

Comment: PHPList - http://www.phplist.com/